# Can I use this flexible tee on a 2" copper drain?

Tags: plumbing

I have a vented 2" copper drain and am looking to tee off for a adding a washing machine drain line. I saw some pictures of people using couplings to transition from copper to pvs and then adding a long turn pvc wye.

My question is: Could I use [this](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Fernco-2-in-x-2-31-in-x-2-31-in-dia-Flexible-PVC-Tee-Fittings/1000075359) piece instead?

If this does what I think it does, I could slip this in and transition to PVC with this singular part.

Comment: Where do you live ? Fernco’s are not legal in some jurisdictions but may be depending on your location.

Comment: Colorado. Found it at my local Lowe's, but I suppose that doesn't guarantee it's to code

Comment: I have lived in Denver but that was in 79

Comment: Tried to say I have used no hubs or ferncos back then helping my uncle bill , he is gone as is my aunts 2nd husband Bob. I haven’t been back for a long time but we used them back them so if things are the same you should be ok.